# python-making strings line up in a column exactly n spaces from left

Tags: python, string, format

In python, is there a way to print a string to a file so that it is exactly n spaces from the leftmost column? For example, I have the following lines in a file:

```
fname1 lname1 ID1 num1
fname2 mname2 lname2 ID2 num2
fname3 mname3 lname3 ID3 num3
```

and I want all the names (first name, last name, and possibly middle name) to be in a column of width 20 with all the first names on the very left. Then I want all the IDs to be in a column of width 10 with all the IDs on the very left of that column of width 10, and finally I want all the nums to be in a column of width 10 so that all the IDS are on the very left of that column of width 10.

For example, the output should be:

```
fname1 lname1             ID1       num1
fname2 mname2 lname2      ID2       num2
fname3 lname3             ID3       num3
```

I tried using

```
line=inpf.readline()
parts=line.split()
line_size=len(parts)
for i in range(0,line_size-2):                                                                                  
    outf.write(parts[i]+' ')
outf.write('{0:>20}'.format(ID))
```

but this just makes ID to be 20 spaces to the right of **lname**.

Comment: what's the maximum width of an ID? are the various name values guaranteed to be less than 20 minus that value? if not, how do those cases get handled.

Comment: the max length of an ID is 10 characters; for each line, the total numbers of characters used for the names (first name, last name, and possibly middle name) is less than 20.

Comment: Your input makes no sense in comparison to your output, where is ` lname3` and how has `ID1` moved to the last column?

Comment: does this boil down to: you want three columns of data of 20, 10 and 10 chars width, with the first column of values (names) left aligned and the other two right aligned?

Comment: yes, sorry if i'm not being clear. i want all the names to be in a column of width 20, and all the fnames to be on the very left of that column of width 20, all the ids to be in a column of width 10, with all the ids on the very left of that column of width 10, and then all the nums to in a column of width 10, with all the nums on the very left of that column of width 10

Comment: @user45264 write exactly that into the question. That makes this MASSIVELY easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from this comment on the question:

> i want all the names to be in a column of width 20, and all the fnames to be on the very left of that column of width 20, all the ids to be in a column of width 10, with all the ids on the very left of that column of width 10, and then all the nums to in a column of width 10, with all the nums on the very left of that column of width 10

That makes this MUCH easier.

```
row = "{:20}{:10}{:10}"  # build formatter string

with open('path/to/file.txt') as inf:
    lines = [line.split() for line in inf]

for fname, mname, lname, id, num in lines:
    col1 = ' '.join([fname, mname, lname])
    col2 = id
    col3 = num
    print(row.format(col1, col2, col3))
```

In Python3, you can elegantly handle a missing middle name by doing:

```
for *names, id, num in lines:
    print(row.format(' '.join(names), id, num))
```

Comment: thank you very much! a slight modification of this code to account for missing middle names worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are handeling mname but I think this should work according to your original question.

```
st1 = fname + ' ' + lname
outf.write(st)
ln1 = len(st)

if ln1 > 20:
    do something acc to your requirement

st2 = ' ' * (20-ln) + ID
outf.write(st2)

ln2 = ln1 + len(st2)
if ln2 > 30:
    do something acc to your requirement

st3 = ' ' * (30-ln2) + num1
outf.write(st3)
```

Comment: Yeah I know. I was waiting for a more pythonic answer to this question but as no one answered I thought of helping OP through this. Anyways I will remove it as soon as someone writes a better answer.

Comment: Don't remove it, it's valid. I'm trying to write something cleaner up, but honestly I'd probably be better-served just forking `tabulate`!